# Excel-VBA Insert five empty rows below each group of name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in the middle of trying to do the above but fail. referring to the image below, i need to insert five empty rows below the 4th row (john lee) and another five empty rows below 7th row (bryan key) and another five below 9th row (casey carton) and so on, i got 30+ groups of different name to do. wondering how to write vba for this? thanks.

[image: name]

Answer (score 3):

So 5 blanks after a change in sorted column A?

```
Const blanks = 5
Dim lastValue As String, i As Long, r As Long
Do
    r = r + 1
    If r > 1 And lastValue <> Cells(r, 1).Value Then
        If Cells(r, 1).Value = "" Then Exit Do
        For i = 1 To blanks
            Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Next
        r = r + blanks
    End If
    lastValue = Cells(r, 1).Value
Loop
```

the `1` in `Cells()` is the column index, i.e. `1 == A`

Comment: I love how this will run headlong into the bottom of the sheet and crash :-)  Oh, you unrestricted `Do Loop`. @Kwai Lum, consider adding `If r > lastRowIWantToCheck Then Exit Do` before the `Loop` statement.

Comment: I did not bother to check for a completely empty column - which is the only scenario that would cause it to run-away - otherwise it will break the loop on the 1st empty cell (line 6)

Comment: Whoops, yeah, sorry! I was running it on an empty column in my head.

Comment: @Kwai Lum: you should really be thanking Alex K... and accepting his answer.